# Oracle average salary for each department

Tags: oracle, join, average

I have the following code, which finds the average salary for each department and it works fine.

I'm having a problem adding department_name to the output. I know I have to JOIN the tables but I'm unable to get that to work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks to all who answer.

```
CREATE table dept  (department_id, department_name) AS
SELECT 1, 'IT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'SALES'  FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE employees (employee_id, manager_id, first_name, last_name, department_id, sal,
serial_number) AS
SELECT 1, NULL, 'Alice', 'Abbot', 1, 100000, 'D123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 'Beryl', 'Baron',1, 50000,'D124' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 'Carol', 'Chang',1, 100000, 'A1424' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, 'Debra', 'Dunbar',1, 75000, 'A1425' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, NULL, 'Emily', 'Eden',2, 90000, 'C1725' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 3, 'Fiona', 'Finn',1, 88500,'C1726' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7,5, 'Grace', 'Gelfenbein',2, 55000, 'C1727' FROM DUAL;
 
SELECT
    department_id,
    ROUND(AVG(sal), 2) AS AVERAGE_SALARY
FROM employees 
group by 
department_id;

Expected output

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME AVERAGE_SALARY
1    IT         82700
2    SALES 72500
```

Comment: You can add `department_name` to both `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` list while joining the tables.

Comment: @Barboros I know what ever you group by needs to be in the SELECT and I was  trying to avoid that. Thanks for responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is only one `department_name` in each group then you can join the tables and use an aggregation function on the `department_name`:

```sql
SELECT e.department_id,
       MAX(d.department_name) AS department_name,
       ROUND(AVG(e.sal), 2) AS AVERAGE_SALARY
FROM   employees e
       INNER JOIN dept d
       ON (e.department_id = d.department_id)
GROUP BY e.department_id;
```

Or, you can aggregate and then join:

```sql
SELECT e.department_id,
       d.department_name,
       e.average_salary
FROM   (
         SELECT department_id,
                ROUND(AVG(sal), 2) AS average_salary
         FROM   employees
         GROUP BY department_id
       ) e
       INNER JOIN dept d
       ON (e.department_id = d.department_id);
```

Which, for your sample data, both output:

> | DEPARTMENT_ID | DEPARTMENT_NAME | AVERAGE_SALARY |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | SALES | 72500 |
> | 1 | IT | 82700 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=827306683f7186b262420e3dea602554)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like this:

```sql
SELECT
    d.department_id,
    d.department_name,
    ROUND(AVG(e.sal), 2) AS AVERAGE_SALARY
FROM employees e inner join dept d on e.department_id = d.department_id
group by 
d.department_id, d.department_name;
```

Here's an example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=156f4e503bc3d6bfed3009137acacb23

Join the employees with department based on department_id.

When you do group by, include the 2 fields not included in the statistics. That'll give you statistics for the 2 fields you are looking for.

Your result will be

> ```
> DEPARTMENT_ID | DEPARTMENT_NAME | AVERAGE_SALARY
> ------------: | :-------------- | -------------:
>             2 | SALES           |          72500
>             1 | IT              |          82700
> ```